# How to execute a PowerShell function by passing parameters using VBA

Tags: excel, powershell, parameter-passing, vba

I have been trying to execute a PowerShell function (`countLines`) that takes an input parameter `fileName` from VBA. I have referred some answers from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17034887/can-i-pass-a-vba-variable-into-a-called-powershell-script) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405750/calling-a-specific-powershell-function-from-the-command-line) but they are not working for me. The following are my attempts to do the same (`fname` is a VBA variable that I am sending as a parameter to the VBA routine that contains the following line of codes):

The contents of `fileReader.ps1` are:

```bsh
function countLines {
    param([string]$logFile);
      #The directory path may differ for others according to the machine's source code repository
    $scriptPath = Resolve-Path "..\..\testFolder";
    $varHolder = -join($scriptPath, "\logFileCount.txt");
    $linesb4Exec = Get-Content $logFile;
    $nLines = $linesb4Exec.Count;
    Clear-Content $varHolder
    $nLines | Out-File $varHolder
    #For second attempt, I am adding the following too
    #echo $nLines;
}
```

First Attempt:

```vb
Call Shell("powershell  -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted ""D:\Temp\fileReader.ps1"";countLines -fileName """ & fname & """", vbMaximizedFocus))
```

Second Attempt:

```vb
Dim strCommand As Variant, WshShell As Variant, WshShellExec As Variant, output As Variant
strCommand = "powershell -command ""& { . ""D:\Temp\fileReader.ps1"";countLines -logFile """ & fname & """ }"""
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Run(strCommand)
output = WshShellExec.StdOut.ReadAll
```

Using this, I am getting an error: Type Mismatch.

Third Attempt (I tried hardcoding everything in my PowerShell file and removed the function and just running a block of code):

```vb
Call Shell("powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file ""D:\Temp\fileReader.ps1""", vbMaximizedFocus)
```

and changing the above powershell script to:

```bsh
$logFile = "C:\somepath\Logs\Log.txt";
$varHolder = "D:\testing\testFolder\logFileCount.txt";
$linesb4Exec = Get-Content $logFile;
$nLines = $linesb4Exec.Count;
Clear-Content $varHolder
$nLines | Out-File $varHolder
```

This seems to be working.

I will be glad if someone could help me to call any PowerShell function with parameters using VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basically two mistakes in your attempts:

- `powershell "D:\Temp\fileReader.ps1";countLines -fileName ...`
  This cannot work, because the script file is executed in a child context while you're calling the function in the parent context. You need to [dot-source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx) the file to make its content available in the current context.
- `Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Run(strCommand)`
  Here you're confusing the [`Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky.aspx) and [`Exec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ateytk4a.aspx) methods. The former returns an integer (the exit code of the external command), the latter a [`WshScriptExec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2f38xsxe.aspx) object (and only that object provides access to `StdIn`, `StdOut` and `StdErr` of the external process). You're getting a type mismatch because you try to assign the integer return value using the [`Set`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4afksd44.aspx) keyword, which must only be used when assigning objects to variables.

The commandline from your second attempt is the right approach if you want to stick with `-Command` and dot-sourcing the file. Use single quotes inside the PowerShell scriptblock to avoid quotefusion and execute the commandline with the [`Shell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk.aspx) function:

```vb
cmd = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ""&{. 'D:\Temp\fileReader.ps1';countLines -logFile '" & fname & "'}"""
Shell cmd
```

With that said, if the function is the only code in your script it'd be simpler to parameterize the script and run the code directly from it:

```bsh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [string]$LogFile
)

$scriptPath = Resolve-Path "..\..\testFolder"
$varHolder  = Join-Path $scriptPath "logFileCount.txt"
@(Get-Content $logFile).Count | Out-File $varHolder
```

Run the script using the parameter `-File` like this:

```vb
cmd = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""D:\Temp\fileReader.ps1"" -LogFile """ & fname & """"
Shell cmd
```

Beware that the path `..\..\testFolder` is relative to your current working directory, not to the location of the script. For the latter use `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`.

---

If something doesn't work add the parameter `-NoExit` to the commandline (so the PowerShell window isn't closed automatically), and call the `Shell` function with the option [`vbNormalFocus`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x91s3x5x.aspx) to run the process in the foreground.

```vb
cmd = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -File ""D:\Temp\fileReader.ps1"" -LogFile """ & fname & """"
Shell cmd, vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: Oops...Sorry, my bad...I'll edit it soon... Thanks for pointing out

Comment: That worked! :) And you implicitly sorted out one of my doubts that I forgot to ask as for how could I stop PowerShell window to close automatically. I wasn't able to identity the problem that the path was not getting resolved s you rightly pointed it out... Bravo for such a well descriptive answer! I need to do a lot of reading...

Comment: It will be great if you can specify as how can I correctly capture the return value of a PowerShell function in my VBA. As you have already pointed out, the return value using the above actually fetches me the exit code, so that's not working for me.

Comment: Please post a new question for that.