# Calling Powershell function from CMD

Tags: powershell, cmd

I have a script with this function inside:

```
function init
{
Write-Output "test output"
}
```

I want to call it from the command line (not from PS), but these do not work:

```
C:\Scripts>powershell -command "& { c:\Scripts\sc.ps1; init }"
init : The term 'init' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:17
+ .\sc.ps1; init
+           ~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (init:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
C:\Scripts>powershell -file c:\Scripts\sc.ps1 -command init
C:\Scripts>
C:\Scripts>powershell -file .\sc.ps1 -command init
C:\Scripts>
```

Execution policy is unrestricted.

Hints from:
[Calling a specific PowerShell function from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405750/calling-a-specific-powershell-function-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Just a typo: dot-sourcing is missing the dot: `{ c:` -> `{ . c:`

Comment: Thanks. So silly!  I should paid more attention to the accepted answer and not to the others. This works: `powershell -command ". .\sc.ps1; init"`